# SelectAll not working in Dialog WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm not sure what's going wrong but I can't select the Text of my TextBox in a dialog.

I added a `FirstTimeLoadedHandler` to Loaded in my view where I select the text:

```
public ParticipantView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += FirstTimeLoadedHandler;
}

private void FirstTimeLoadedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SurnameBox.Focus();
    Keyboard.Focus(SurnameBox);
    SurnameBox.SelectAll();
}
```

However my textbox is in Keyboard-Focus, but not selected at all. I'm not sure why it's not working.

I thought it has something to do with my databinding but the data should be received before Loaded fires or am I wrong?

Comment: Try to debug through your code, put a break point in your handler and have a look at the contents of your text box. If it's empty, you'll have to use another event (like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sourceupdated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Guess you're right. The TextBox is empty so it's going to be called before my value is assigned. However I can't just focus it after every change because then it would select the text while typing...

Comment: All of your code works on a normal WPF window, it must be something to do with your data-binding

Comment: You could simply unsubscribe from the SourceUpdated Event after it has been handled for the first time. That would ensure you will only select it once. It's a little bit hacky though.

Comment: @Frame91: Use Select All option in LostFocus Event, it will work or else you should have content before select the Textbox..

Comment: Actually I have two TextBoxes. Firstname, Lastname. When I start the dialog Firstname should be focused. This is it... If I use LostFocus than Lastname would have the focus but with your solution it wouldn't. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would work fine with two small changes. The first is that obviously, selecting all on a `TextBox` that has no text in it will have no effect. Secondly, if you focus it *after* calling `SelectAll`, you'll have more luck. Try this:

```
private void FirstTimeLoadedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SurnameBox.Text = "This text is selected";
    SurnameBox.SelectAll();
    Keyboard.Focus(SurnameBox);
}
```